# ElasticSearch Terms Aggregation Order Case Insensitive

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to sort the buckets of a terms aggregation in elasticsearch case-insensitive. Here is the field mapping:

```
'brandName'       => [
    'type'     => 'string',
    'analyzer' => 'english',
    'index'    => 'analyzed',
    'fields'   => [
        'raw' => [
            'type'  => 'string',
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Note that this data structure here is for PHP.

And the aggregation looks like this:

```
aggregations => [
    'brands' => [
        'terms' => [
            'field' => 'brandName.raw',
            'size'  => 0,
            'order' => ['_term' => 'asc']
        ]
    ]
]
```

This works, but the resulting buckets are in lexicographical order.

I found some interesting docs [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sorting-collations.html) that explained how to do this, but it is in the context of sorting the hits, not the aggregations buckets.

I tried it anyway. Here is the analyzer I created:

```
'analysis' => [
    'analyzer' => [
        'case_insensitive_sort' => [
            'tokenizer' => 'keyword',
            'filter' => [ 'lowercase' ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

And here is the updated field mapping, with a new sub-field called "sort" using the analyzer.

```
'brandName'       => [
    'type'     => 'string',
    'analyzer' => 'english',
    'index'    => 'analyzed',
    'fields'   => [
        'raw' => [
            'type'  => 'string',
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
        ],
        'sort' => [
            'type'  => 'string',
            'index' => 'not_analyzed',
            'analyzer' => 'case_insensitive_sort'
        ]
    ]
]
```

And here's the updated aggregation portion of my query:

```
aggregations => [
    'brands' => [
        'terms' => [
            'field' => 'brandName.raw',
            'size'  => 0,
            'order' => ['brandName.sort' => 'asc']
        ]
    ]
]
```

This generates the following error: `Invalid term-aggregator order path [brandName.sort]. Unknown aggregation [brandName]`.

Am I close? Can this kind of aggregation bucket sorting be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that this kind of advanced sorting on aggregations is not yet supported and there is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6917) that is tackling this (slated for v2.0.0).

There are two other points worth mentioning here:

1. the `brandName.sort` sub-field being declared as `not_analyzed`, it's contradictory to also set an `analyzer` at the same time.
2. The error you're getting is because the `order` part can only refer to sub-aggregation names, not field names (i.e. `brandName.sort` is a field name)

Comment: It varies. Most of them are one or two words. Some are several words.

Comment: It is worth noting that the data set I'm working with is small enough that doing a client side sort post-query may be preferable to an ugly hack in ElasticSearch.